# How to use Substring output as like parameter in a query in DB2

Tags: db2

How to use substring of a column from one table as like to a column in some other table ? For example I tried using the below query however its give me error.

```
SELECT LABORCODE FROM labor WHERE worklocation like (SELECT substr(location,1,4) FROM person)+ '%';
```

If Substring of location from PERSON table returns 1234 then the final output should appear as below,

```
LABORCODE    LOCATION
A            1234
B            12345
C            123456
```

Basically the substr (location) from PERSON table should be used as a input to worklocation field in LABOR table with LIKE function.

Comment: What is the error? Your subquery returns more than one string

Comment: @data_henrik DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.59.81 is the error . Yes my sub query returns more than 1 row . If I modify my subquery to return only 1 row then the following error occurs DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, SQLERRMC=DECFLOAT, DRIVER=3.59.81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` instead of `+`:

```
SELECT LABORCODE 
FROM labor 
WHERE worklocation like 
(
SELECT substr(location,1,4) 
FROM person 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) || '%';
```

I've added the `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` clause just in case, since the subselect must not return more than 1 row.

If your subselect returns multiple rows, then you may rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT LABORCODE
FROM labor
WHERE EXISTS  
(
SELECT 1 
FROM person  
WHERE labor.worklocation LIKE substr(person.location, 1, 4) || '%'
);
```